# firebase rules write permission for only one user

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm having trouble to write Firebase database rules.  I would like to give write permission to only one user i.e admin user.  All others will have read permission.

Please help me to write a Firebase database rule to restrict other users to write.

Comment: isn't it something like if(auth=={uuid of your choice}) or can you not put a string in the rules?

Comment: how does your database-structure look like?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771808/how-to-only-allow-one-admin-user-to-write-firebase-database/41775839#41775839

Answer (score 2):

```
"rules":{
  "users" : {
     "$uid" : {
        ".read" : "auth!=null",
        ".write" : "$uid === adminUID"
      }
   }
}
```

This will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just replace auth.uid with the uid of the admin you want to be able write to the database.

You can read the documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/

Answer (score 1):

I assume your access rights apply to the entire JSON data and admin is the one who has access to firebase console. So, below rule will work,

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,   // (or) ".read": "auth != null"
    ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.isAdmin == true"
  }
}
```