# Restrict access to Firebase-Database with auth.uid not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I want to restrict access to my Firebase Database, so that only the users I authorize can write to it.
But the solution almost everywhere proposed doesn't seem to work for me.

I always get an 401 (unathorized) Error in my Console.

I tried two ways of checking wheter the right user is logged in or not, but none of them worked for me.:

**1. uid hard-coded in rules:**

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth.uid === 'UID'")",
    }
}
```

**2. uid in database**

```
{
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)",
    }
}
```

In both ways I used the uid provided in the Firebase-Authentication overview.
I use Google as Signin provider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/#section-authorization):**

> Here's an example of a rule that grants write access for authenticated
>   users to `/users/<uid>/`, where `<uid>` *is the ID of the user obtained
>   through Firebase Authentication.*

---

**Edit:**

For a specific path and current obtained user through Firebase Authentication, this should help:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "YourSpecificPath": {

     "$uid": { // where <uid> is the ID of the user obtained through Firebase Authentication
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"    
        ".read": true,

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, give the `uid` directly:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth.uid === 'dJrGShfgfd2'"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I don't want to grant access for one user to a specific path.
I want to achieve that one user can write to all Data. And all the others can't. Is that possible?

Comment: Then do I have to wrap my entire Database into the uid?
The User should have something like a Admin-functionality

Comment: You can give the `uid` directly (as the admin) in this case too. Check frank's answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41775839/4409113 updated the answer.

Comment: Okay, I feel really stupid now... 
I switched to axios and forgot to send the idToken with my Patch-request... and oh wonder: it's unathorized... Thank you anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

**All code-samples are correct**

All of the Code-Snippets, in the question and in the answer of Mohsen
work. 
I just forgot to send the idToken with my patch-request.

Code to get the idToken:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#retrieve_id_tokens_on_clients

Authenticate with an idToken:

```
https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com/users/ada/name.json?auth=<ID_TOKEN>
```

from: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth

Comment: Then I believe you should accept my answer since it was correct. However, you got my upvote for the explanation. This will be helpful for the future searches :) Happy coding.