# How to set one user as admin in firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have Users database in which I want each authenticated user to read and update his own data. I also want to set one admin user who can read and update all the users' data in the database.

I tried doing like this - [How to only allow one admin user to write Firebase Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771808/how-to-only-allow-one-admin-user-to-write-firebase-database)

But it didn't quite work.

My database structure is:

```
- Users
   -key1
     -email: xyz
   -key2
     -email: abc
```

This is what I tried. Here I added admin user in firebase auth and his auth id is say - s94ZwBcP
However, I dont have any key in the database for this user (as I dont need it).

```
"rules": {
     "users":{
       "$uid":{
         ".read" : "$uid == auth.uid || auth.uid === 's94ZwBcP'", 
         ".write": "$uid == auth.uid || auth.uid === 's94ZwBcP'"
      }
     }
```

Comment: What doesn't work about these security rules? Can you edit your question to also include the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I dont get back the keys, when I hit the database, although if I turn the rules to "true" for all, I get back they keys

Comment: If some code that you run against these rules doesn't work, edit your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to read from `/users`. Since there is no `.read` rule defined on `/users`, nobody can read that node.

To allow the admin to get (and modify) the list of all users, modify your rules to:

```
"rules": {
  "users":{
    ".read" : "auth.uid === 's94ZwBcP'", 
    ".write": "auth.uid === 's94ZwBcP'",
    "$uid":{
      ".read" : "$uid == auth.uid", 
      ".write": "$uid == auth.uid"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked. Didnt realise that uid was for the keys and user was in general.